# Unicode Error Django syncdb

Tags: python, django, postgresql, unicode

I'm working on a project in Django python. It uses `psycopg2` module, and PostgreSQL database, of course.

I've never had this problem before, I don't know if it's due to a .dump i made of the database, but when I try `python manage.py syncdb` it's throwing this error message:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf3' in postition 177: ordinal not in range (128)
```

This is the first time this happens to me on this project, what puzzles me is that it wasn't throwing it before, btw the character it is referring is on a `.json` file, a string containing the hash of an image to be more specific.

On my `settings.py` file, I already have the `# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-` string, any ideas about this?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT

Complete traceback of error:

```
(django1.5) F:\autanacenditel\backup\autana\comun>python manage.py syncdb 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 12, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "F:\autanacenditel\django1.5\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__i
nit__.py", line 453, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "F:\autanacenditel\django1.5\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__i
nit__.py", line 392, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "F:\autanacenditel\django1.5\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\bas
e.py", line 229, in run_from_argv
stderr.write('%s: %s' % (e.__class__.__name__, e))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf3' in position 177
: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Add traceback of the error.

Comment: Solved, re-downloaded the branch from git, but never knew why this happened, thank you anyways.